# I'm searching for a software for reading pdf files on the pc

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer

As the title says, I would like an application (best if free) for .pdf files reading on my computer.

I often read academic papers and I would like an alternative to Acrobat Reader.

Ideally with this new program I should be able to:

-Make notes

-Mark pages with different bookmarks (to read, read, to review etc..) better if customizable bookmarks. Bookmarks can be added to the document index.

-Highlighting tools for paragraphs and lines

-Possible to have black background for more comfortable reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/), to quote the opening page:

> Your research, anywhere. For students and researchers Mendeley is a
>   free reference manager and academic social network. Make your own
>   fully-searchable library in seconds, cite as you write, and read and
>   annotate your PDFs on any device. Showcase your work and assess the
>   impact of your research.

- Free
- Multi-platform
- Allows highlighting and annotating pdf files
- Allows referencing pdf files
- Highlights & annotations are available across devices

[image: Mendeley Desktop On Windows 8.1]

Comment: This piece of software could be a great solution, do you happen to know if it stores your files online in the company's cloud or it just acts as a collector (as iTunes for music files on your pc)

Comment: Both - it can store and order them locally and online.

Answer (score 2):

[Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/) is the one I use. It's pretty fast, and generally very compatible. I find it reads just fine PDF files that Google Drive chokes on.

- it does allow notes.
- It only has one kind of bookmark, but you can name each bookmark.
- It has highlight, strikeout and underline
- I don't think you can change the background.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PDF-XChange Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) and I think it is excellent. It's really light weight and quick to load (really quick) but has all the features you'd expect! I've just checked and as far as I can see it has all the features you are looking for and more. This is the free version as well, it says it's a trial but there's no time limitations or nags - you just can't use some of the Pro features which you probably won't need anyway.

Failing that, you might consider using Microsoft OneNote if you have it. I don't have much experience with it but I know it is really powerful and I'm pretty certain it can help you - especially if you're doing research! There are some good tutorials online.

Comment: I agree. PDF-XChange Viewer supports having several PDF files open at the same time. Even the free version has comments and annotating tools.